# Pandas Datatypes to Python Native Datatypes

Tags: python, pandas

Is there a way to return a single standard python object when selecting the Max value from a DF column?

Test Code:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"A": [1,2,3,4], "Date": ['2010-01-01 00:00:01', '2010-02-01 00:00:01', '2019-01-01 00:00:01', '2010-01-01 00:00:01']})

df['Date']= pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
```

Test 1:

```py
type(df["Date"].max())

pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp
```

Test 2:

```py
type(df["A"].max())

numpy.dtype[int64]
```

Ideally I want to have a function that I can pass the DF and column name to and get the max value in a python standard object without having to do a load of if type == style statements.

Pesudo-code idea:

```py
def find_max(df, col):
    max_val = df[col].max()
    max_val.into_python_type()
    return max_val

x = find_max(df, 'Date')

type(x)

datetime.datetime

x = find_max(df, 'A')

type(x)

int
```

EDIT

```
df.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 4 entries, 0 to 3
Data columns (total 2 columns):
 #   Column  Non-Null Count  Dtype         
---  ------  --------------  -----         
 0   A       4 non-null      int64         
 1   Date    4 non-null      datetime64[ns]
dtypes: datetime64[ns](1), int64(1)
memory usage: 192.0 bytes
```

[image]

```
pd. __version__ 
'1.2.4'
```

Python 3.9.4

Comment: In the case of the timestamp what python type would you want it converted to? python doesn't have a timestamp format so I'd assume either string or float?. In the case of `df["A"].max()` you can just change it to `max(df["A"].tolist())` and it will come out as a python type.

Comment: Hi, timestamp to a string would work for my usecase.

Comment: In that case just cast it to a string, ie. `str(df['Date'].max())`

Comment: But what about integers? They need to stay as Int

Comment: To quote my first comment "In the case of `df["A"].max()` you can just change it to `max(df["A"].tolist())` and it will come out as a python type.".. If you do that it comes out as a python int. That said I don't understand why you want it to be a python int and not a numpy int, what difference does it make to you?

Comment: `type(df['A'].max())` returns `int` for me, can you show the output of `df.info()` and specify the pandas and python versions you’re using ?

Comment: Also do you want this for any data type? Or only a few possible types?

Comment: Added some edits to cover your coments @Cimbali Covering String and numeric types would be good. Datetime is a bonus but I can work without that.

Answer (score 0):

Solved this with some of the ideas in the comments:

```py
    def _get_max_val(self, df, param_name):
        try:
            max = df[param_name].max().tolist()
        except AttributeError:
            max = str(df[param_name].max())
        return max
```

Gives me what I need